# R - date format after cbind

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column that looks like:

```
> head(merged_2$ReferenceDate)
[1] "2008-03-31 UTC" "2008-03-31 UTC" "2010-03-31 UTC" "2010-06-30 UTC" "2008-03-31 UTC"
[6] "2008-03-31 UTC"
```

but when I use cbind to get:

```
test <- cbind(merged_2$ReferenceDate)
> head(test[,1])
[1] 1206921600 1206921600 1269993600 1277856000 1206921600 1206921600
```

How can I get the dates to appear as dates and not as numbers?

```
> typeof(merged_2$ReferenceDate)
[1] "double"
> typeof(test[,1])
[1] "double"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By formatting it as date with `as.Date()`, but it needs an origin...

```
my_dates <- as.Date(c("2008-03-31 UTC", "2008-03-31 UTC", "2010-03-31 UTC", "2010-06-30 UTC", "2008-03-31 UTC" ,"2008-03-31 UTC"))
cbind(my_dates)
#      my_dates
# [1,]    13969
# [2,]    13969
# [3,]    14699
# [4,]    14790
# [5,]    13969
# [6,]    13969
as.Date(cbind(my_dates), origin='2000-01-01')
as.Date(cbind(my_dates), origin='1970-01-01')
```

So for your example you have to modify this a little

```
as.Date(cbind(merged_2$ReferenceDate), origin='1970-01-01')
```

Comment: I get these results: > `head(test[,1])
[1] "3306409-02-08" "3306409-02-08" "3479094-05-18" "3500620-11-24" "3306409-02-08"
[6] "3306409-02-08"`

Comment: I guess you have to play around with the origin a little. Depending on windows or unix systems, these numbers are a bit different...